# How to block contact in Android Programmatically?

Tags: java, android

```
public void block() {


   **// I want to block the contact number method here** 

}
```

I have one button named block contact when i click on that button i want to call this block(); method and i want to block contact number from android

Comment: its an old thread its probably not possible now due to restrictions.